# Overlay two bitmap images in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, overlay

I need to overlay two images (say, JPEG and PNG with transparency).

Input: 
- JPEG image
- PNG image

Output:
- JPEG image with PNG applied.

What is the best approach to do that?

Thank you in advance for the replies and hints!

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a DrawingGroup like this:

```
var group = new DrawingGroup();
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"...\Some.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)), new Rect(0, 0, ??, ??)));
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"...\Some.png", UriKind.Absolute)), new Rect(0, 0, ??, ??)));

MyImage.Source = new DrawingImage(group);
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to convert it back into BitmapImage?

Comment: @Mohib: I have no idea. You need to have a BitmapSource or a Stream to use an encoder and I can't find any mechanism to get from a DrawingImage or DrawingGroup to a BitmapSource. Try asking this as a new question.