# Better way to overlap (superimpose) images in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I had a requirement to overlay two images in WPF for a project. On searching around, I finally ended up using DrawingImage class using DrawingGroup as suggested here: [Overlay two bitmap images in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352358/overlay-two-bitmap-images-in-wpf)

```
var group = new DrawingGroup();
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"...\Some.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)), new Rect(0, 0, ??, ??)));
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"...\Some.png", UriKind.Absolute)), new Rect(0, 0, ??, ??)));

MyImage.Source = new DrawingImage(group);
```

But I got stuckup as I am unable to convert it back to BitmapImage for further manipulations.

Any other ideas on overlapping images in WPF?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you need to convert back?

Comment: I want to rotate, merge the image with other images and print the final output.

Comment: you can apply a `RotateTransform` to your `DrawingGroup`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawinggroup.transform.aspx. You can nest the `DrawingGroup`s, gaining any desired effect. This way you avoid converting back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my requirement using DrawingVisual class. For more info, refer here: [Drawing Bitmaps – DrawingImage and DrawingVisual](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/555-drawing-bitmaps-drawingimage-and-drawingvisual-.html?start=1)